# Knockout JS Validation to existing view model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

This is my current code unmodified: http://jsfiddle.net/XABtF/

I am currently using both [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) & [Knockout Validation](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation)

I have read through the documentation on both and tried implementing them to my existing script, both haven't ran successfully. Here is how I attempted to implement the Knockout Validation: http://jsfiddle.net/yNVeF/

My script is very simple, I would like to just put validation on two observables like this:

```
self.emailAdd = ko.observable("");
```

I have tried doing it like this:

```
self.emailAdd = ko.observable("").extend({required: { message: 'Please supply your email address.' }});
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is it not working? Looks fine to me... assuming you actually included the validation plugin.

Comment: I think my issue is binding the validation to the save button, I've got a several step ajax form, and I'm not grasping the syntax of including this script into the submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placed the jQuery validate below my applyBindings and binded the view model name with 'save':

```
$("#getAcc").validate({ submitHandler: authViewModel.save });
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As per comments below, if you use the validation plugin, the extenders are a part of that - if not... /Edit

The extenders are not pre-written - you need to add your own required extender as demonstrated in the documentation here.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

```
ko.extenders.required = function(target, overrideMessage) {
  //add some sub-observables to our observable
  target.hasError = ko.observable();
  target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

  //define a function to do validation
  function validate(newValue) {
     target.hasError(newValue ? false : true);
     target.validationMessage(newValue ? "" : overrideMessage || "This field is required");
  }

  //initial validation
  validate(target());

  //validate whenever the value changes
  target.subscribe(validate);

  //return the original observable
  return target;
};
```